# How do I connect my new tap's flexible hoses to my copper supply pipes?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, plumbing-fixture

I bought a tap, and am not entirely sure what I should be doing with it. I received a flexible hose pipe to connect it to the mains.

The current tap however seems to use plastic joints into a metal solid pipe. If i remove the pipe (going upwards in the image), what type of adaptor would i need to put the flexible hose on please.

I am good with my hands, and I know how to drain the system etc. But just don't know much about joining pipes and the standards that are used.

Thanks for any help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show your local hardware store salesperson this post and they'll set you up with the required fittings. You'll probably end up cutting the copper above those quick connectors and installing a male threaded end using a compression fitting. Then you can just screw on the tap supply.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the feedback. Oddly, the copper pipes get smaller as they go up towards the tap. I'm not sure at what point they start to taper. I will follow your instructions and ask one of the local stores. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some adapters which are designed for Flexi tap to quick connectors.

You simply screw one end on, then insert the other into the quick connectors like you would any other pipe.

Now that I've done it, it seems straight forward. But at the time i wasn't sure of the connection types or possibilities. Or how they worked.

Really cheap and easy to do. Tool-less infact.

[image: image of adapter]